# Swift tabbar add selector to tabItem

Tags: swift, xcode

Im using a custom popover menu for my tabbar controller. I need the tabbar item to open the menu. I need to add the tabbar item without them leading to any viewcontroller. I try to set them to nil in my tabcontroller class but it will not accept a nil item. If im able add them to the tabbar it will be triggered in the delegate

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

the way i solved it is to set the selected index back to where i want             `tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0`